# Cannot recover Pluggable Database

Tags: oracle, rman

I am new to RMAN and I'm trying to recover a pluggable database with `recover pluggable database <pdbname>`

Before issuing the `recover pluggable database` command, I perform the following steps:

1. Backup the pluggable database with incremental backup+autobackup
2. Shutdown the database
3. Delete control file from CDB and all files from PDB I want to recover(because i want to simulate restoring a PDB when the control files are missing)
4. RMAN target and issue `STARTUP NOMOUNT`
5. Restore the Control File from the autobackup(which generated when i do an incremental backup on PDB)
6. Mount the database and issue `restore pluggable database <pdbname>`
7. After all files for PDB and Control file in CDB are restored, I run `recover pluggable database <pdbname>`.

But when i run this last command, this error happens

```
    RMAN> recover pluggable database pdb;
    
    
    
    Starting recover at 23-JAN-22
    
    using channel ORA_DISK_1
    
    
    
    RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
    
    RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
    
    RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
    
    RMAN-03002: failure of recover command at 01/23/2022 23:59:47
    
    RMAN-06067: RECOVER DATABASE required with a backup or created control file
```

What is causing this error and how to fix it? I already restored the  Control File from backup and this error still occurred.
Do I need to backup  both CDB and PDB in order to recover the PDB when the controlfile are missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controlfile is at the CDB level. Since you have restored the controlfile, you need to recover the instance as a whole (CDB + PDBs). If you issue the RECOVER DATABASE command while connected to the root container, it should recover the CDB plus the PDB whose files you restored.

HTH

Comment: what did you get 
recover database using backup controlfile;

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Backup the *pluggable database* with incremental backup+autobackup
> 2. Shutdown the database
> 3. Delete control file **from CDB** ...

The problem here is that Pluggable "databases" are not "real", Oracle **Databases**.
To all intents and purposes, I suggest you consider them to be **Tablespaces** on steroids.

The only Oracle **Database** here is the Container Database.
Trash the [CDB's] Control File and you lose the *whole* Container Database (and so need to restore it).